# How to get the name of a list member in a list in R?

Tags: r

Consider `my.list`:

```
my.list <- list(member.one = rnorm(3), 
                member.two = data.frame(a = rnorm(2), 
                                        b = rnorm(2) + 1))
my.list
# $member.one
# [1] -0.4803475 -0.7755822  0.9740834
# 
# $member.two
#            a         b
# 1 -0.7026612 1.1467156
# 2  0.3708469 0.6776552
```

Is there a way to get the name of `my.list$member.one`, `member.one`?

```
magic.function(my.list$member.two)
# [1] "member.two"
```

`names()` does not help me:

```
names(my.list$member.two)
[1] "a" "b"
```

Comment: What is the motivation here?

Comment: In the most trivial case, `fun <- function(x) { y <- deparse(substitute(x)); sub(".*\\$(.+)", "\\1", y) }; fun(my.list$member.two)`; not that there is any utility in that. But generally speaking, the name of an element in a list is a property of the list itself -- not the element -- so I don't think there is any way for a component in a list to "know" its own name.

Comment: Or `as.character(quote(my.list$member.two)[[3]])`.

Comment: hahaah quite hacky solutions, both are totally acceptable! Thanks. @lmo the motivation is that I have a list with different names, with a specific pattern, like `$one.table`, `$one.variables`, `$two.table`, `$two.variables` etc. and I want to apply different functions to each one of them according to a specific string patter (in this case 'table' or 'variables').

Comment: So you want to use a switch statement and switch code based on what its list name is.  In your control structure (for loop or whatever) I'd consider using something like `for (x in names(my.list))` instead of  `for (x in my.list)` if possible.  Then you can have your switch statement use the character vector x, and use `my.list[[x]]` to get the element.